# FPGA random LED blink ( 4 LED)

Tags: random, vhdl

I am trying to create a vhdl code that will randomly blink four LEDs. After pushing a button that corresponds to the blinking led, a score will be displayed using 7 segment after 60 seconds.

Can anyone help me in generating random LED blink for the 4 LEDs?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at a [Linear Feedback Shift Register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LFSR). That'll give you a pseudo-random sequence of whatever length you want, and it's both effective and easy to implement in VHDL.

Depending on "how random" you need your sequence to be, you could for instance create a 16 bit long LFSR, and then use four arbitrarily selected bits from this to display (instead of using four consecutive bits, which might make the next value easier to guess, depending on the implementation).

Comment: Use something else to initialise the LFSR : maybe the length of a "reset" button press measured by a fast clock. If it always starts at the same number it'll always give the same sequence, and Rainman will learn the sequence...